# Motivating the definition of adjoint equivalence

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Recently I have been trying to convince myself that the most natural definition for equivalence between categories is the notion of *adjoint equivalence* rather than simply *equivalence*. Of course, every equivalence of categories can be "upgraded" to an adjoint equivalence, but conceptually I feel that in many ways the notion of adjoint equivalence is more natural.

Adjoint equivalences have the following advantages over (non-adjoint) equivalences as a notion of equivalence:

1. For a functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, any functor $G:\mathcal{D} \to\mathcal{D}$ which is forms an adjoint equivalence with $F$ is unique up to unique isomorphism (in fact, this holds for any pair of adjoint functors). On the other hand, if we require that $F,G$ is just an equivalence, then the isomorphism need not be unique.
2. If $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective then the only sensible way to construct $G: \mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ such that $F,G$ is an equivalence actually yields an adjoint equivalence.

I have a feeling that the 2-category structure on the category of ((locally) small) categories $\mathrm{Cat}$ is behind this phenomenon: non-adjoint equivalences are equivalences from the point of view of vertical composition, and the triangle identities for an adjunction ensure that $F,G$ are an equivalence from the point of view of horizontal composition.

However, this isn't quite satisfactory. If I wanted to naively write down what $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}:G$ being horizontal-inverses to one another means, I would write down the following: There exists natural transformations
$$\eta: id_{\mathcal{C}}\Rightarrow GF ,\overline{\eta}:GF \Rightarrow id_{\mathcal{C}}$$
$$\varepsilon: FG \Rightarrow id_{\mathcal{D}} ,\overline{\varepsilon}:  id_{\mathcal{D}}\Rightarrow FG$$such that
$$\overline{\eta} \ast\eta =\eta \ast\overline{\eta} = id_{\mathcal{C}}$$
$$\overline{\varepsilon} \ast\varepsilon =\varepsilon \ast\overline{\varepsilon} = id_{\mathcal{D}}$$
However, unpacking these definitions just gives
$$\eta_x \circ \overline{\eta}_x=id_x, \varepsilon_x \circ \overline{\varepsilon}_x=id_x $$
so this simply boils down to equivalence.

My questions are the following:

1. Am I right in thinking that adjoint equivalence is the "right" notion of equivalence, rather than non-adjoint equivalence?
2. If so, is this ultimately due to the 2-category structure on $\mathrm{Cat}$?
3. In this context, how can one motivate the triangle identities? Perhaps there are many laws we want $F,G$ to satisfy and it turns out that $\eta,\varepsilon$ being isomorphisms and satisfying the triangle identities is sufficient for all of these laws holding (in much the same way that the pentagon identity in a bicategory is a sufficient condition for all of the infinitely-many association laws which one might desire)

---

Here I use $\circ$ to refer to vertical composition and $\ast$ to refer to horizontal composition

Comment: To answer: (1) Yes, adjoint equivalences are the well-behaved notion of equivalence. (2) sort of. There is a general notion of equivalence internal to a 2-category. Here again the notion of adjoint equivalence is the proper, well-behaved notion. I would say that the fundamental reason behind this is the first point that you list: adjoint equivalences satisfy the appropriate uniqueness principle. Fixing some functor $F$, we have that $F$ being an adjoint equivalence is a property of $F$ (since there is at most one way this can happen), instead of being an additional structure on $F$.

Comment: However, I don't think this ties into your comment about the triangle identities implying $F$ and $G$ are inverses with respect to horizontal composition. In fact, I'm not sure it makes sense to say ''inverses with respect to horizontal composition"

Comment: Question (3) is a bit more subtle and much more open ended. The triangle identities are exactly the condition you need to impose on the unit and counit to get that the following map is an isomorphism: $f \mapsto G(f) \cdot \eta_c : D(Fc , d) \to C(c , Gd)$. We can also think of the triangle identities as exactly the condition necessary to force each component $\eta_c$ of the (co)unit to be a universal arrow from $c$ to $G$.

Comment: In the context of equivalences, we want want to have a notion of "a category of equivalences from $C$ to $D$. Moreover, we want this to be a full subcategory of the functor category $C \to D$. But this happens if, and only, if the notion being an equivalence is a property.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer to this now. The "right" notion of equivalence of categories (in my opinion) consists of natural transformations
$$\eta: id_{\mathcal{C}} \Rightarrow GF,\overline{\eta}: GF \Rightarrow id_{\mathcal{C}} $$
$$\varepsilon: id_{\mathcal{D}} \Rightarrow FG,\overline{\varepsilon}: FG \Rightarrow id_{\mathcal{D}}$$
subject to the following relations: Consider the functors $id_{\mathcal{C}},id_{\mathcal{D}}$ along with all the iterated composites of $F,G$ (i.e. $F,G,FG,GF,FGF,GFG$, etc). Let $F_i=FG...F$ (or $FG...G$) of length $i$ with $F_0=id_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $G_i=GF...G$ (or $GF...F$ etc) of length $i$ with $G_0=id_{\mathcal{D}}$. Let
$$\eta_{i,j}=id_F \ast \ldots \ast\eta \ast\ldots \ast id_F: F_i\Rightarrow F_{i+2}$$
have $\eta$ in the $j$-th position (where $j$ is even) and define $$\overline{\eta}_{i,j}:F_i\Rightarrow F_{i-2} \text{ (for $j$ even)}$$
$$\eta_{i,j}':G_i\Rightarrow G_{i+2} \text{ (for $j$ odd)}$$
$$\overline{\eta}_{i,j}':G_i\Rightarrow G_{i-2} \text{ (for $j$ odd)}$$
$$\varepsilon_{i,j}:F_i\Rightarrow F_{i+2} \text{ (for $j$ odd)}$$
$$\overline{\varepsilon}_{i,j}:F_i\Rightarrow F_{i-2} \text{ (for $j$ odd)}$$
$$\varepsilon_{i,j}':G_i\Rightarrow G_{i+2} \text{ (for $j$ even)}$$
$$\overline{\varepsilon}_{i,j}':G_i\Rightarrow G_{i+2} \text{ (for $j$ even)}$$
similarly. We require that any two sequences of the above natural transformations from $F_a,F_b$ have to be equal (after vertical composition) and the same for $G_a,G_b$.

**Claim:**

> The data $(F,G,\eta,\varepsilon,\overline{\eta},\overline{\varepsilon})$ forms an equivalence in the above sense if and only if $\eta,\varepsilon$ are natural isomorphisms with $\eta^{-1}=\overline{\eta},\varepsilon^{-1}=\overline{\varepsilon}$ and $(F,G,\eta,\varepsilon)$ is an adjoint equivalence.

**Sketch proof:**
($\Rightarrow$): This direction is easy to see - the relations $\eta\circ\overline{\eta}=\overline{\eta}\circ\eta=id_{\mathcal{C}},\varepsilon\circ\overline{\varepsilon}=\overline{\varepsilon}\circ\varepsilon=id_{\mathcal{D}}$ and the triangle identities for adjunctions are both instances of the laws given above.

($\Leftarrow$): It is not hard to convince oneself that for any sequence of the given natural transformations from $F_a$ to $F_b$ (or $G_a$ to $G_b$), the corresponding commutative diagram can be "filled in" by triangles, and hence that we need only check relations of a triangular shape. Now consider how the insertion and deletion of $GF$ or $FG$ by the natural transformations overlap. The only nontrivial cases are when $GF$ or $FG$ have been inserted/deleted in exactly the same position, or when the $F$ in an inserted $GF$ overlaps with the $F$ in a deleted $FG$ (or some permutation of $F$, $G$, "inserted", "deleted" etc.) But these are exactly the laws for equivalence/adjointness respectively! $\square$